# Wordpress based website blocked by commercial proxy policies

Tags: wordpress, proxy

I have developed quite a number of sites using wordpress, many of which are not blogs and wordpress is only being used as a CMS although I am finding more and more that sites powered by wordpress are being blocked as they are categorised as "blogging/social".  The sites in question are neither a blog nor social related.

Has anyone come across this before and if so is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of sites using WP outside the blog/media realm.  Obsfucate that you're using WP by restricting IPs into wp-admin.  In addition, you could rename wp-content to something else.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/226128?replies=8

This however alone isn't certain to change the classification of existing sites.